# Is a $CD(K,\infty)$ space a length space?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete and separable metric space endowed with a nonnegative Borel measure $\mu$ with support $X$ and satisfying
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu(B(x,r))<\infty,\quad\mbox{for every }x\in X\mbox{ and }r>0,
\end{eqnarray}
where $B(x,r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$ in $X$ w.r.t. the metric $d$.

Let $(X,d,\mu)$ be a $CD(K,\infty)$ space in the sense of Sturm. Is $(X,d)$ a length space?

Many thanks.

Comment: I answered, but considered not to: the answer is in Sturm's paper so you obviously did not search enough before asking. Do not forget on MO you are asking people for their time, so you should first try by yourself and check the literature thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in Sturm's paper: the support of $\mu$ must be a length space, but obviously the whole space $X,d$ need not be geodesic, as everything outside the support of $\mu$ is invisible to the $CD(K,\infty)$ solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, which of Sturm's papers are you referring to?

Comment: I know the Remark 4.6 (iii) in Sturm's paper Acta Math. 2006 (I). But the refence measure is assumed to be finite. So I'm not sure of your answer. And I'm sorry for wasting your time!